# Start Action in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am developing a ClassLibrary-Project in Visual Studio 2008. I want something to check. I have file 'index.html' in root of my project. I need set StartAction to open this file with some browser. I found StartAction in "Project Properties->Debug->Start Action". I can choose "Start external program" or "Start browser with URL", but they require absolute path to my file. I want to do it with relative path (like '$(ProjectDir)index.html'). How I can do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using relative path for "Start external program" in VS.NET 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774745/using-relative-path-for-start-external-program-in-vs-net-2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately none of the Visual Studio Macros are replaceable in the Debug "Start External Program" menu.  It also appears that relative paths are considered from the location of devenv.exe.  I don't know if that's 100% true but it appears to be through experimentation.

I think your best bet at this point is to hard code the path.  The path is stored in the user specific project file and is typically a machine specific file.  The majority of Source Code Control providers don't check this in by default for that reason so you won't mess up other devs.

Comment: There is actually a way to accomplish this. See this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774745/using-relative-path-for-start-external-program-in-vs-net-2010