# Using relative path for "Start external program" in VS.NET 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've seen a few posts related to this topic but none with any conclusive answers...

When debugging my VS.NET 2010 app, I'm trying to start an external program whose location is relative to the project path.  I've seen some indications that macros (like $(ProjectDir)) were supported in earlier versions of VS.NET, but they don't seem to work in VS.NET 2010.  Using relative path notation just gives me an error that the path is invalid.

Has anyone run into this?  If so, how did you address?

Thanks.

Comment: Macros can still be used, but need to be set manually in the `.csproj` XML file. After doing this, don't forget to delete the relevant sections from `.csproj.user` file, if any.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found the answer [**here**](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/04/16/how-to-use-relative-paths-when-debugging-in-visual-studio-2008).

In the event that the above link goes dead, the summarized answer is as follows:

1. Macros don't work here, so forget about that.
2. Environment variables don't work either, so forget about that as well.
3. It turns out that Visual Studio.NET (at least 2008 and 2010) uses one of two paths as the base for any relative path specified in the **Start external program** setting...

If Visual Studio.NET was launched by clicking on the SLN file in Explorer, the base path will be the folder (including the "\") where the SLN resides.  Once I modified my relative path to account this and then launched VS.NET 2010 by double-clicking the SLN file, my external program correctly launched when hitting F5.

If Visual Studio.NET was launched from the shortcut on the Start Menu and then the SLN was opened from within Visual Studio.NET, the base path will be **[Visual Studio install path]\Microsoft Visual Studio ["9.0" or "10.0" depending on whether using VS.NET 2008 or 2010]\Common7\IDE\**.

I guess it makes sense now, but it still kinda stinks that VS.NET will only find my external program correctly depending on how I launch VS.NET.

Comment: Thanks for posting a link to my site. You guys are awesome!

Comment: I know I'm posting a comment on an answer that's more than 2 years old, but I'd like to clarify this "strange behaviour."  It is, actually, not that strange.  If I understand correctly, the "Working Directory" concept is one that originates from the OS, not VS itself.  As far as the OS is concerned, the working directory is the directory from which VS was invoked (Solution directory when started from the .sln, VS directory when started from link).  What _may_ be odd is that VS doesn't explicitly change the working directory whenever a solution is loaded.

Comment: @MetaFight The strange behavior is that VS allows to use macros like `$(TargetDir)` anywhere but in the `Debug` section of the project properties, although in can be set manually in the `.csproj` file.

Answer (score 47):

I know this is a little late to the party, but here's how we do it. The key to this is to set the 'OutputPath' explicitly to the Build directory.  This re-bases it to working directory and not the VS install directory.

1. Update output path for the project to be:
   `<OutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\</OutputPath>`
2. Update StartProgram for the project to be:
   `<StartProgram>$(OutputPath)Relative.exe</StartProgram>`

Here is a sample configuration PropertyGroup:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '0-Local|AnyCPU'">
   <!-- default values you should already have in your csproj -->
   <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
   <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
   <DebugType>full</DebugType>
   <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
   <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>

   <!-- actual output path and start action definition -->
   <OutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\</OutputPath>
   <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
   <StartProgram>$(OutputPath)NServiceBus.Host.exe</StartProgram>
   <StartArguments>NServiceBus.Integration</StartArguments>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I had trouble making your suggestion work. Could you edit your post to include a cut'n'paste of your .csproj file?

Comment: +1, Awesome. I had fought this for a long time, now we don't need to fight with project settings between dev machines.

Comment: NOTE: I modified this a little and put these in the main <PropertyGroup> (the one w/o the condition attribute) and changed OutputPath to "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\$(Configuration)\" (w/o quotes).

Comment: To add to @MarkJMiller's comment, i added the <StartAction>, <StartProgram>, and <StartArguments> node to the property group with the following condition, and it works for all debug and release build configs:  Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' "

Comment: In a complex projects that contains third-parties located in subdirectories, such as libs, this suggestion will not work, because Visual Studio will try to find dependencies near the .svhost file. So in this case a trick approach is to create csproj file and add such things to it.

Comment: I think the key is not to set the 'OutputPath' to the Build directory to re-base it to working directory, but to set them manually in the `.csproj` XML file. Because VS doesn't allow to use macros in the `Debug` section of the project properties. You can also use $(TargetDir), e.g. $(TargetDir)NServiceBus.Host.exe

Comment: Sweet! Note the macro can also be an environment variable you have set - in my case I set an Environment variable on all my machines for the root folder for all my code as %CODEZ% which I can use in the .csproj file as $(Codez). As long as the subfolder structure is standardised then it works on all machines.

Comment: does not work at leased starting from VS 2022 ... im sure it did before

Answer (score 31):

Similar to what Yobi21 suggested, editing the project file and adding these lines to the main `<PropertyGroup>` in the project file worked for me:

```xml
<StartAction>Program</StartAction>
<StartProgram>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Path\Relative\To\CSProj\Folder</StartProgram>
<StartArguments>Any Required Arguments</StartArguments>
```

> Watch out for the properties in the `.csproj.user` file overriding those in your regular project file.
>   Note: Starting with Visual Studio 2017, these properties are contained in the `launchsettings.json` file.

This one stumped me until I deleted the entries.

Comment: I +1'd the original answer, only to find out that this is a better solution! Adding these properties to the main PropertyGroup works even when you open the solution from within Visual Studio.

Comment: Awesome. I added those lines twice (once in the debug block, once in the release block) instead of the main properties section. Works great, too.

Comment: After deleting the `.csproj.user` file, you can no longer open the Project Properties in VS. Was this not a problem for you guys?

Answer (score 15):

$(SolutionDir) will not work if you use it directly in VS2010 in the start external programm, but if you close your solution and open the YourProject.csproj.user with notepad, you can change the path and include the $(SolutionDir).

Reopen VS 2010 and it works like a charm.

here an example of my project "ApplicationService_NSB.csproj.user"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>$(SolutionDir)\Super\ApplicationService_NSB\bin\Debug\NServiceBus.Host.exe</StartProgram>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Setting a StartWorkingDirectory would also be useful, mine didn't want to run without it. Something like this: <StartWorkingDirectory>$(SolutionDir)\Super\ApplicationService_NSB\bin\Debug</StartWorkingDirectory>

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful. I was banging my head on this problem for an hour or more. +1

Comment: do not forget to relaunch your visual studio..
i wasted 15 mins. because i ignored the statement "Reopen VS"
works in VS 2013. too

Comment: This works, but you can no longer edit project properties in VS after doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**You can change the .user in notepad while solution is closed** to even include relative paths. It is ,however, horrific.
Example:

```
<StartProgram>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(SolutionDir))))\MyCustomBindir\MyCustomProgram.exe</StartProgram>
```

This is without scroll

```
<StartProgram>
$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName( $(SolutionDir))
))\MyCustomBindir\MyCustomProgram.exe
</StartProgram>
```

[image]

The windows predefined folders can be used too.

```
<StartProgram>$(AppData)\MyCustomBindir\MyCustomProgram.exe</StartProgram>
```

Remeber the xml conifg **.user** file is parsed when loading the solution not when pressing the **Start** debug button so any changes to the .user file must happen while the solution is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Something I stumbled upon, which seems to not interfere or redefine existing macros:
Looks like you can define your own macros and use them

```
<StartAction>Program</StartAction>
<MyMacro>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)your_folder_path_here\</MyMacro>
<StartProgram>$(MyMacro)MyApp.exe</StartProgram>
```

Answer (score -6):

The list of available macros for vs2010 are listed in this web [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx)

ProjectDir macro are listed as available for VS2010

$(ProjectDir) The directory of the project (defined as drive + path); includes the trailing backslash '\'.

But if you're having throubles with it, you can try using SolutionDir.

$(SolutionDir) The directory of the solution (defined as drive + path); includes the trailing backslash '\'.

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried that and it doesn't work.  I don't think macros are supported for the "Start external program" setting.

Comment: Have you tried your suggestion? Macros don't work in this case.